# How to improve this python code?

Tags: python, list

I am doing a problem in which i have to code about this problem-

```
>>> getNumbers(10)
[100, 64, 36, 16, 4, 0, 4, 16, 36, 64, 100]
>>> getNumbers(9)
[81, 49, 25, 9, 1, 1, 9, 25, 49, 81]
```

I am getting answers with my code but i am not satisfied with my code,please suggest some options to improve this code.

```
def getNumbers(num):
myList=[]
mylist=[]
if num%2==0:
    for numbers in range(num,-2,-2):
        myList.append(numbers**2)
    for numbers in range(2,num+2,2):
        mylist.append(numbers**2)

    print myList+mylist

elif num%3==0:
    for numbers in range(num,-1,-2):
        myList.append(numbers**2)
    for numbers in range(1,num+2,2):
        mylist.append(numbers**2)

    print myList+mylist

else:
     print(mylist)
```

4 for loops!!! this is what teasing me here!!!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
def getNumbers(n):
    return [i * i for i in range(-n, n + 1, 2)]
```

Comment: Don't use lambda like that. It's wrong

Comment: I am just a beginner.i am doing list problems which are available on pyschool.i do not know about lambda.i also don't know why they close my question.it is my 2nd question on this forum.i just want to improve my code, i know you guys can tell me best options.i can't ask smart questions because till now i am not at that level...but thanks for your help guys:)) You have given me a best way to eliminate those for loops...

Comment: "i also don't know why they close my question." It says exactly why, right there: it is off topic for Stack Overflow. This site is not about how to improve your coding style, it is about how to solve your coding problems.